# What is RESULT keyword in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/reservewords.htm) I found a `RESULT` keyword, but I could not find any documentation about it.

Comment: It's still in the 11g docs as well - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/reservewords.htm#LNPLS019 - either a misprint, or possibly just a word Oracle was thinking about using later on, but never got around to it, or decided against it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There sre two references to RESULT in the master index, but they don't lead anywhere interesting (code examples for [Transparent Gateway](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b16218/dev_apps.htm#sthref1058)).

Certainly, RESULT is not included in the V$RESERVED_WORD view.  Furthermore we can use RESULT in our own code without problem:

```
SQL> declare
  2      result pls_integer;
  3  begin
  4      result := some_number;
  5      dbms_output.put_line(result);
  6      dbms_output.put_line('That''s NumberWang!');
  7  end;
  8  /
16912
That's NumberWang!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**tl;dr** Forget about it.

Comment: Thanks. I got confused since Notepad++ too highlights `RESULT` as a keyword. Maybe they to referred the same list.